# How do I compute $\;\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am working through the Algorithm Design Manual. Chapter 2 Problem 2 has us evaluate the return value of a function which consists of three nested loops which can be expressed by the following triply nested summation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1
$$

I get stuck on the very first step of evaluating the outermost summation:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i}(??)
$$

Comment: I think it's instructive to write summations as for loops when programmers are learning to deal with summations. This triple summation can be written as the following triple loop: for i in range(1,n): for j in range(1, i): for k in range(j,i+j): print 1. How many 1s are printed?

Comment: Hint: rewrite the k sum using $k'=k-j$

Comment: The extreme right sum is $1+1+1+...1=i+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *innermost* summation has the form
$$
\sum_{k=\rm start}^{\rm finish} 1
$$
You are counting the value $1$ starting at $k={\rm start}$ and ending at $k={\rm finish}$, which means you're counting $${\rm finish} - {\rm start} + 1$$ copies. Note the extra $1$; the answer is not simply ${\rm finish} - {\rm start}$. Check that this general formula works when finish = start, or when start = $1$.

So in your context the value of (??) is $$(i+j)-(j) + 1 = i+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}(i+j-j+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}i(i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$